# How JSON file 'hardcode' to program code build C# (WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have JSON file which comfortable edit in root folder of project.
I load file

```
string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

But when I create build, I want that this JSON file 'hard code' to program. The bottom line is that in the final assembly there would not be a separate json file, but that it would be in the program itself and read from there

How can I make it? Thank you!

(Windows Forms)

Comment: I think there is a translation problem here: "sew" is not a word we normally use in programming. Perhaps you can include some more details and code so that we have a better idea of what you want to do?

Comment: In the title you say WF. That is Work Flow. I think you mean WPF?

Comment: @IMSoP, I tried to make some clarifications)

Comment: @PaulSinnema, sry, I mean WinForms, corrected

Comment: Why is there ASP.Net and WPF in your tags?

Comment: @PaulSinnema, corrected

Comment: Why would you want to embed a JSON file in your program and read it from there? In case the data does not change you could more easy create a class with hard-coded data. You can also use `enum` declaration in your class.

Comment: Use a `resx`, for example. Or just paste the contents of JSON to some cs file.